# Taking a input from user in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using ROR , For my app user input is needed in view.For this i am using this:

```
<%= form_tag("/new", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

My question is,how can i access the text user enter into text field into my controller new action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element `text_field_tag(:q)` should submit a parameter "q", which can then be read on the server by calling `params[:q]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
params[:q]
```

Should get you what you're looking for.